# How to use a singleton for storing the RedisConnection with Booksleeve?

Tags: booksleeve

I'm using Booksleeve 1.1.0.6 (the latest nuget package).

I want so use a single connection for my whole Web Application so I'm storing it in a singleton:

```
public static RedisConnection Conn = RedisConfig.GetUnsecuredConnection(waitForOpen: true);
```

The **RedisConfig.GetUnsecuredConnection** method is the same as used in BookSleeve tests.

When I try to do an operation I get an *InvalidOperationException: The queue is closed* exception:

**[InvalidOperationException: The queue is closed]**
   BookSleeve.MessageQueue.Enqueue(RedisMessage item, Boolean highPri) in C:\Dev\BookSleeve\BookSleeve\MessageQueue.cs:73
   BookSleeve.RedisConnectionBase.ExecuteVoid(RedisMessage message, Boolean queueJump) in C:\Dev\BookSleeve\BookSleeve\RedisConnectionBase.cs:794
   ASP.welisten_booksleevetests_aspx.SaveDictionaryToRedis(Dictionary`2 dictionary) +173
   ASP.welisten_booksleevetests_aspx.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +67
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +25
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +71
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3064

I tried this with the **waitForOpen** parameter set to *true* and *false*

Here is the code I'm trying to execute:

```
 private void SaveDictionaryToRedis(Dictionary<string, string> dictionary)
    {
        using (Mp.Step("Saving Data to Redis"))
        {
            using (RedisConfig.Conn)
            {
                RedisConfig.Conn.Strings.Set(DB, dictionary);

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what was copied, it could be that there is a missing call to:

```
theConnection.Open();
```

which will open the connection and perform various handshakes. Thin the case of a singleton, this would be reasonable to do during the initializer.

However! Perhaps the problem here is that your second example is simply wrong. If `Conn` is, as described, a singleton - then it does not belong to that code, and you should not be using `using`. That would mean it is only usable once, and all subsequent access would fail. Just access the connection; no `using` here.